# Java - how to read .properties files with ${variable} that comes from pom.xml file?

Tags: java, properties, pom.xml

What should I do to read variable ${variable} from .properties file? So far I have functionality that reads "url=https://www.google.com/" with a use of
`properties.getProperty("url"))` and it works.

But what should I do to read variable that comes from pom.xml ?

So in .properties file I have

```
url=https://www.google.com/
browser=${browser}
```

How should I configure pom file to get value from there ?

I want to locate the following code in the pom.xml file

```
<browser>chrome</browser>
```

Any dependencies are needed or other things ?

Thank you

Comment: Hello, it is not clear where do you want to read the property defined in pom.xml. Is it in Java code?

Comment: This is java, I want to read property in any class.

Comment: Assuming you want Maven to replace `${browser}` with `chrome` during the processing of resources, then check out https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Comment: the link does not say precisely how to configure pom.xml file

Comment: Yes, it does. It shows an example step by step.